# How to display array of images in Silverlight ComboBox?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, combobox

I have array of objects with created images (Object.Image), i want to show images in combobox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="typeSelection" ItemsSource="..." DisplayMemberPath="Image"></ComboBox>
```

Combobox shows Image.ToString(), not image itself, how to fix it.

Comment: What is the actual type of the `Image` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the ItemTemplate for the combobox. something like this....
(this is for an array of paths to the images, not actual images)

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding MySourcePath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

[here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightComboBox12022008122421PM/SilverlightComboBox.aspx) is a nice example of comboboxes in silverlight

Comment: I changed Image to BitmapSource, but your answer was the closest, so i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of  a ComboBox is to use the ItemSource as the source of a list of items and the DisplayMemberPath as the name of a property to use for a TextBlock.Text value. Therefore it looks at your "Image" property and does a .ToString() to convert it for the TextBlocks in the list.

Instead you need to implement a ComboBoxItem Control Template, to describe the elements in each displayed item (text, images, whatever). Those controls will themselves contain bindings to the properties on your objects. e.g:

```
<Image Source={Binding Image}/>
```

As Muad'Dib pointed out (30 seconds earlier), the Image must be a string that is the path of the image, not an actual image object.